# Where are text replacements stored?

Tags: macos, keyboard, icloud, shortcut

I want to import Apple text replacements from a text file. I want to import a large amount of shortcuts to the system so I am wondering if that is possible.

[image: Example of Apple keyboard shortcuts I'm talking about]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Select all the shortcuts you wish to export and drag them to a location in Finder. This will create a ‘Text Substitutions.plist’.
2. Move this file to another account/computer, then drag it back on top of the list to import the file.

Full details are provided by Apple in their support document on the matter:

- [How to export and import text substitutions on your Mac - Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/back-up-and-share-text-replacements-on-mac-mchl2a7bd795/mac) ([archive page](https://web.archive.org/web/20190408215722/https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204006))

---

In direct answer to the question title, the actual location used for storing substitutions is within the UserDictionary.db somewhere within `~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/`. This is not something you should modify manually. Also - since this data is iCloud backed - some versions and point in time it used an older storage method and API (iCloud Core Data) and now it's using a more modern key value store (CloudKit).

- https://daringfireball.net/linked/2017/09/26/stucki-text-replacements
- https://www.macstadium.com/blog/science-confirmed-text-replacements-do-not-sync/

Comment: does not answer the question but supplies a solution. Really need to know where they are stored to delete the file...